# AddView and commitNow

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am facing problem of adding view to **LinearLayout**. If you add a **view**(using `addView()`) and a **fragment**(with `commitNow()`) one after another in a loop, then all the views are always shown first and then all the fragments. Why is this happening?

RedFragment:

```
class RedFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_red) {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val binding = FragmentRedBinding.bind(view)
        for (i in 0..4) {
            val tvTime = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.text_layout, binding.liveEventsContainer, false)
            tvTime.id = View.generateViewId()
            (tvTime as? TextView)?.text = "10:0$i"
            binding.liveEventsContainer.addView(tvTime)
            
            val contentFragment = BlueFragment()
            childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.liveEventsContainer, contentFragment, null)
                .commitNow()
        }
    }
}
```

fragment_red:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/red">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/liveEventsContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

BlueFragment:

```
class BlueFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_blue) {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val binding = FragmentBlueBinding.bind(view)
    }
}
```

[What i see after launch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlQAg.jpg)

Comment: why not just use a recyclerview ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody Yes, it would be easier with recyclerview, but this problem always shows up with LinearLayout. I'm just wondering why this is happening.